# JSDoc - Documentation for object property that is defined later

Tags: javascript, oop, documentation, jsdoc

How to document an object property/method, when this property/method gets added to the object **later**, after the object has been initialized?

Example:

Let's say that I declare the following object. Documentation of `ID` and `name` work fine:

```
let AppUser = {
   /** The user's id */
   ID: 0,
   /** The user's name */
   name: "guest",
};
```

Later, I decided to add a property (let's say in another js file):

```
/** The role of the AppUser */
AppUser.role = "admin";
```

In that case, `App.role`'s documentation does not work. At least, VSCode does not open the tooltip to inform me about its description.

What I do now, is declare an empty property inside the object: `role:null,` and also write its documentation. This workaround works OK.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work the object definition should be a bit different. Something like the following:

**a.js**

```js
const AppUser = {}

AppUser.ID = 0
AppUser.name = 'guest'
```

**b.js**

```js
AppUser.role = 'admin'
```

**c.js**

[image: Screenshot]